# How to get the time of specific timezone using javascript, but without being relevant to the current system time?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone

Now, before you mark this as a duplicate, please note that all the useful answers in the possible duplicate provide functions which work in relation to the current system time, which I cannot accept.

What I want, is that the current time in, say, for example, New York, be consistent to all users, no matter what their time settings are.

For example, I have two computers here, and one is 3 seconds behind the other, and this leaves an unacceptable gap, as my task involve pinpoint precision (slightly exaggerated, but you know what I mean).

How can I overcome this? Must I get the server time and somehow convert it? If so, I'm using PHP.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what it is you need to accomplish?

Comment: [datetime.settimezone](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript NTP time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522191/javascript-ntp-time) - You're wanting to sync possibly inaccurate clocks client-side, for which NTP is the right protocol. On top of that you need to do your timezone calculations.

Comment: Not a dup, and that link is bad because it claims NTP but really is just passing the time in json and not using the NTP protocol at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope to not be wrong but javascript is loaded on user machine, not on the server so you will allway get the visitor date/time using javascript. you can use php to get the date/time because is loaded on the server and pass the dates to javascript.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a timezone library to do this in JavaScript. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

The scripts are small, but because they require the timezone database, it can get unwieldy for a client application.  You're probably better off doing the conversion server side.  Perhaps the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library will be useful to you.