# How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have date time in a particular timezone as a string and I want to convert this to the local time. But, I don't know how to set the timezone in the Date object.

For example, I have `Feb 28 2013 7:00 PM ET,` then I can

```
var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setFullYear(2013);
mydate.setMonth(02);
mydate.setDate(28);
mydate.setHours(7);
mydate.setMinutes(00);
```

As far as I know, I can either set the UTC time or local time. But, how do I set time in another timezone?

I tried  to use the add/subtract the offset from UTC but I don't know how to counter daylight savings. Am not sure if I am heading the right direction.

How can I go about converting time from a different timezone to local time in javascript?

Comment: [This answer may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/439871/1046057)

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they are UTC.

Comment: worth reading this article https://medium.com/@toastui/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d, the conclusion is you can't in JavaScript but you can use libraries like Moment Timezone to do it

Comment: @JohnLord No, the local getters simply convert the stored UTC time _into_ the _host_ timezone. For example, do `d = new Date()` then `d.getHours()` in the console, change your computer's time zone by an hour, and try `d.getHours()` again. There is no local time zone information stored in `d`.

Comment: I also wrote an article around this issue at https://medium.com/@EyeDin/time-and-time-zone-headaches-in-javascript-ae4d873a665d . Might worth reading. :)

Answer (score 883):

### Background

JavaScript's `Date` object tracks time in UTC internally, but typically accepts input and produces output in the local time of the computer it's running on. It has very few facilities for working with time in other time zones.

The internal representation of a `Date` object is a single number - namely *timestamp* - representing the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, without regard to leap seconds.

#### There is no time zone or string format stored in the Date object itself.

When various functions of the `Date` object are used, the computer's local time zone is applied to the internal representation.  If the function produces a string, then the computer's locale information may be taken into consideration to determine how to produce that string.  The details vary per function, and some are implementation-specific.

The only operations the `Date` object can do with non-local time zones are:

- It can parse a string containing a numeric UTC offset from any time zone.  It uses this to adjust the value being parsed, and stores the UTC equivalent.  The original local time and offset are not retained in the resulting `Date` object.  For example:

  ```
    var d = new Date("2020-04-13T00:00:00.000+08:00");
    d.toISOString()  //=> "2020-04-12T16:00:00.000Z"
    d.valueOf()      //=> 1586707200000  (this is what is actually stored in the object)
  ```
- In environments that have implemented the [ECMASCript Internationalization API](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/) (aka "Intl"), a `Date` object can produce a locale-specific string adjusted to a given time zone identifier.  This is accomplished via the `timeZone` option to `toLocaleString` and its variations.  Most implementations will support IANA time zone identifiers, such as `'America/New_York'`.  For example:

  ```
    var d = new Date("2020-04-13T00:00:00.000+08:00");
    d.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
    //=> "4/12/2020, 12:00:00 PM"
    // (midnight in China on April 13th is noon in New York on April 12th)
  ```

  Most modern environments support the full set of IANA time zone identifiers ([see the compatibility table here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_date_tolocaletimestring_iana_time_zone_names)).  However, keep in mind that the only identifier *required* to be supported by Intl is `'UTC'`, thus you should check carefully if you need to support older browsers or atypical environments (for example, lightweight IoT devices).

#### Libraries

There are several libraries that can be used to work with time zones.  Though they still cannot make the `Date` object behave any differently, they typically implement the standard IANA timezone database and provide functions for using it in JavaScript.  Modern libraries use the time zone data supplied by the Intl API, but older libraries typically have overhead, especially if you are running in a web browser, as the database can get a bit large.  Some of these libraries also allow you to selectively reduce the data set, either by which time zones are supported and/or by the range of dates you can work with.

Here are the libraries to consider:

**Intl-based Libraries**

New development should choose from one of these implementations, which rely on the Intl API for their time zone data:

- [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) (successor of [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/))
- [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) (extension for [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/))
- [Day.js](https://day.js.org/) (when using its [Timezone plugin](https://day.js.org/docs/plugin/timezone))

**Non-Intl Libraries**

These libraries are maintained, but carry the burden of packaging their own time zone data, which can be quite large.

- [js-joda/timezone](https://github.com/js-joda/js-joda/tree/master/packages/timezone) (extension for [js-joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/))
- [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)* (extension for [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/))
- [date-fns-timezone](https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone) (extension for older 1.x of [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/))
- [BigEasy/TimeZone](https://github.com/bigeasy/timezone)
- [tz.js](https://github.com/dbaron/tz.js)

** While Moment and Moment-Timezone were previously recommended, the Moment team now prefers users chose Luxon for new development.*

**Discontinued Libraries**

These libraries have been officially discontinued and should no longer be used.

- [WallTime-js](https://github.com/sproutsocial/walltime-js)
- [TimeZoneJS](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)

#### Future Proposals

The [TC39 Temporal Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) aims to provide a new set of standard objects for working with dates and times in the JavaScript language itself.  This will include support for a time zone aware object.

#### Common Errors

There are several approaches that are often tried, which are in error and should usually be avoided.

##### Re-Parsing

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleString('en', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'}))
```

The above approach correctly uses the Intl API to create a string in a specific time zone, but then it incorrectly passes that string back into the `Date` constructor.  In this case, parsing will be implementation-specific, and may fail entirely.  If successful, it is likely that the resulting `Date` object now represents the wrong instant in time, as the computer's local time zone would be applied during parsing.

##### Epoch Shifting

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + someOffset * 60000);
```

The above approach attempts to manipulate the `Date` object's time zone by shifting the Unix timestamp by some other time zone offset.  However, since the `Date` object only tracks time in UTC, it actually just makes the `Date` object represent a different point in time.

The same approach is sometimes used directly on the constructor, and is also invalid.

Epoch Shifting is sometimes used internally in date libraries as a shortcut to avoid writing calendar arithmetic.  When doing so, any access to non-UTC properties must be avoided.  For example, once shifted, a call to `getUTCHours` would be acceptable, but a call to `getHours` would be invalid because it uses the local time zone.

It is called "epoch shifting", because when used correctly, the Unix Epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`) is now no longer correlated to a timestamp of `0` but has shifted to a different timestamp by the amount of the offset.

If you're not authoring a date library, you should not be epoch shifting.

For more details about epoch shifting, watch [this video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rnIHsqABfM&feature=youtu.be&t=12m30s) from Greg Miller at CppCon 2015. The video is about `time_t` in C++, but the explanation and problems are identical.  (For JavaScript folks, every time you hear Greg mention `time_t`, just think "`Date` object".)

##### Trying to make a "UTC Date"

```
var d = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(), d.getUTCMilliseconds()));
```

In this example, both `d` and `utcDate` are identical.  The work to construct `utcDate` was redundant, because `d` is already in terms of UTC.  Examining the output of `toISOString`, `getTime`, or `valueOf` functions will show identical values for both variables.

A similar approach seen is:

```
var d = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(), d.getUTCMilliseconds());
```

This is approach passes UTC values into the `Date` constructor where local time values are expected.  The resulting `Date` object now represents a completely different point in time.  It is essentially the same result as epoch shifting described earlier, and thus should be avoided.

The correct way to get a UTC-based `Date` object is simply `new Date()`.  If you need a string representation that is in UTC, then use `new Date().toISOString()`.

Comment: When you do this in the Firebug console:  `var date_time = new Date()`, the value of `date_time` is (for me in AEST) `Date {Sun Aug 21 2016 22:18:47 GMT+1000 (AEST)}` and so therefore it seems it *has* stored a timezone.  How can I ensure `date_time` is purely the UTC time, without any timezone included?

Comment: Hmm, according to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8047885/1063287), it is this:  `new Date().getTime();`

Comment: @user1063287—the *toString* method uses the host timezone offset to produce a date and time in the "local" time zone. The date object itself has a time value that is an offset from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, so effectively UTC. To see the UTC date and time, use [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

Comment: To clarify; the javascript Date *does* record a timezone in addition to the point in time represented by milliseconds since midnight 1970-01-01 UTC.  For more info take a look at the rhino source code @ https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeDate.java

Comment: @redcalx - that is a Rhino specific implementation, but even then, if you scroll to the very bottom you'll see that `private double date` is the only instance field.  Everything else is static, and primarily there for caching environment provided values.  It's not something tracked per-instance, or something you can modify easily.

Comment: Hmm. Ok here'a a thing. If we create two dates, one with new Date(), the other with new Date(Date.UTC(2016,0,1,0,0,0)) and then do toString() on each, then one gives the date/time based on the local timezone, the other the date/time using the UTC timezone. So something somewhere is storing a timezone against each date instance. (test performed in Chrome).

Comment: The `Date.UTC` function is computing the timestamp based on UTC inputs is all.  The output of `.toString()` will be the local time equivalent, and will show the local time zone offset, name, or abbreviation.

Comment: That makes sense; my confusion was caused by the two dates I created having different timezone specifiers when using toString(), that was because I'm in a locale with daylight savings time, and toString() reports a local time, i.e. GMT+1 for dates in the summer, and GMT for dates in the winter.

Comment: @redcalx— *toString* is implementation dependent and may or may not show the time zone in any particular format. Most browsers only return names or abbreviations for common time zones and the UTC offset for others.

Comment: This needs to be updated, as the format of *toString* is now set in the spec. ;-)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411332/1974681) you have a solution using plain [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) Internationalization API

Comment: It is worth to mention another Intl based library - [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs), which has the [smallest footprint](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=dayjs@1.10.7).

Comment: the second answer gives a direct answer, you don't need to read this bible to get where you want.

Comment: @guilhermevictorramalhonatal - Unfortunately the second answer (if you are sorting by score), recommends both re-parsing and epoch shifting, which are errors - as I described in this answer.  The effects can be seen just by clicking the run button.  Even if the parsing works, the Toronto value has the wrong offset and time zone unless Toronto is already your local time zone.

Comment: how do you know the devs of moment prefer users to choose Luxon?

Comment: @netotz - Because I was a core maintainer of Moment for many years, and authored the [project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) notification that says exactly that.

Answer (score 226):

As Matt Johnson said

> If you can limit your usage to modern web browsers, you can now do the
> following without any special libraries:
>
> `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})`

> This isn't a comprehensive solution, but it works for many scenarios
> that require only output conversion (from UTC or local time to a
> specific time zone, but not the other direction).

So although the browser can not read IANA timezones when creating a date, or has any methods to change the timezones on an existing Date object, there seems to be a hack around it:

```js
function changeTimezone(date, ianatz) {

  // suppose the date is 12:00 UTC
  var invdate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: ianatz
  }));

  // then invdate will be 07:00 in Toronto
  // and the diff is 5 hours
  var diff = date.getTime() - invdate.getTime();

  // so 12:00 in Toronto is 17:00 UTC
  return new Date(date.getTime() - diff); // needs to substract

}

// E.g.
var here = new Date();
var there = changeTimezone(here, "America/Toronto");

console.log(`Here: ${here.toString()}\nToronto: ${there.toString()}`);
```

Comment: I'm wondering why this answer isn't getting more love. For my purposes it is absolutely the best solution. In my app, all dates are UTC, but they need to be input or output in explicit IANA timezones in the UI. For this purpose I use this solution and it works perfectly. Simple, effective, standard.

Comment: @logidelic it is a pretty new post. to be honest, i amazed myself when it struck me you could use ``toLocaleString`` to achieve the reverse effect, and yes, this should be common knowledge ! go write an article about it and mention me :-)

Comment: The only bad thing about this is the browser support of toLocaleString() :(

Comment: For a node environment that is not in GMT already, the above code needs to change from  var invdate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { 
        timeZone: ianatz 
     })); into  var invdate = new Date(${date.toLocaleString('en-US', { 
        timeZone: ianatz 
     })} GMT`);

Comment: Browsers are not required to parse the output of *toLocaleString*, so it's based on a faulty premise.

Comment: @RobG Yes, that is true, and strange. All browsers I encountered sofar can parse the output of their own version of toLocaleString.

Comment: Not that strange given the history of *toLocaleString* and that the format is influenced by system regional and language settings that may not be the same when generating the string as when parsing it (e.g. en-GB and en-US). And that's without considering the variations caused by different options. There was a time when IE did not correctly parse the output of its own *Date.prototype.toString*.

Comment: "...why this answer isn't getting more love?" - because the `Date` object it returns is a lie.  Even the example shown, the string output includes the local machine's time zone.  On my computer, *both* results say "GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)", where that is only correct for the first one (Toronto is actually in Eastern Time.)  Beyond just the string output, the timestamp held within the `Date` object has been shifted to a different point in time.  This *can* be a useful technique, but comes with a lot of caveats - primarily that `Date` object functions will not have normal output.

Comment: The String output of `toLocaleString` is correct, but then parsing that into the Date Object will return faulty value since that String would be treated as if it were in the local timezone.

Comment: `I'm wondering why this answer isn't getting more love` @logidelic because it gives the wrong time, should be `date.getTime() - diff`. Made an edit to fix it, hopefully it gets approved.

Comment: @NoSssweat I cant comment on your fix, but tempted to reject it; you also swapped `here` and `there` in the example and yes, then obviously you need to subtract the diff instead of adding it. My example says, if its 17:00 in Toronto now, what time is it here. Your example says, if it's 17:00 here now, what time is it in Toronto.

Comment: @commonpike The original answer says Toronto (EST) is 3 hours behind my time, Vancouver (PST). Which is wrong, Toronto is 3 hours ahead of me. See [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/EwRqWfb.png), this is what I see with your original answer. The `here` and `there` is just for console log and it was wrong. You assigned `here` to toronto and when logging used `there`.

Comment: @NoSssweat you were right and fix approved ;-) Strange, `here` and `there` were apparently swapped by @RobG for some reason.

Comment: This one should get more love.thanks man for saving my day.

Comment: @commonpike— I didn't change anything of substance, I converted the code to a runnable snippet and added the *console.log* line, maintaining here/there as they were.

Comment: This is great, but performance is really slow. I did edge browser profiling check, this function changeTimezone take 2.7ms per run.

Comment: I second @MattJohnson-Pint.  You are having two `Date` objects, which are representing the same point-of-times (same number of seconds passed since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 in UTC), but they are not `==` :(   That's why I believe confusing people with the incorrect fact that "`Date` has an internal `timestamp` in it", is a bad idea.  I would encourage the @chickens solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842203) which takes in timezone + six numbers, and produces ONE single `Date` object.  TL;DR: Two strings for the same point-of-time are fine; but not two Date objects.

Comment: There is an issue in this code with ms. Specifically, 'date' should have its ms set to zero or truncated before processing. For example, do something like one of these:
`date = new Date(date.toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z');` or
`date = new Date(date.setMilliseconds(0));`

Explanation: If the 'ianatz' locale string used by 'invdate' does not include ms, then 'diff' (which uses getTime(), which does include ms) might be off by some number of ms because 'invdate' might truncate ms (setting them to 0) but 'date' still would have ms.

Answer (score 78):

This should solve your problem, please feel free to offer fixes. This method will account also for daylight saving time for the given date.

```
dateWithTimeZone = (timeZone, year, month, day, hour, minute, second) => {
  let date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));

  let utcDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "UTC" }));
  let tzDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timeZone }));
  let offset = utcDate.getTime() - tzDate.getTime();

  date.setTime( date.getTime() + offset );

  return date;
};
```

How to use with timezone and local time:

```
dateWithTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles",2019,8,8,0,0,0)
```

Comment: This solution was fit for my need. I wasn't sure how exactly I can account for daylight saving.

Comment: Why not just return `tzDate` directly?

Comment: Works perfectly fine in a Node js server! (Parse cloud code)

Comment: Very good solution, for me just returning utcDate was what I needed

Comment: This is a bad idea as the format of *toLocaleString* is not specified, and the built–in parser is not required to parse it, especially when options have been included. Further, it may produce unreliable results in areas that observe daylight saving where the date and time to be parsed either doesn't exist (going into DST) or exists twice (goint out of DST), where implementations must make a choice as how to resolve those issues.

Comment: Note that `month` here is 0-based, consistent with the most of internal JS functions for month, which you may not necessarily be familiar with. That's why `dateWithTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles",2019,8,8,0,0,0).toISOString()` produces `'2019-09-08T07:00:00.000Z'`

Comment: @RobG, 1) are you talking about `basic` vs `best fit` of `formatMatcher` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat?  2) Are you talking about that 2 hours per year (0.02%) that doesn't have any answer but possibly an Exception or `null`?

Comment: @Aidin—the *formatMatcher* method isn't relevant to the answer as only one language is supplied. The built–in parser is not required to parse any timestamp generated by *toLocaleString*. DST issues may or may not throw an error, and two different implementations may or may not produce different results. It also assumes a conversion from timezone offset abbreviation based on common names like ET (which are not standardised and are ambiguous) to IANA representative location like "America/Los_Angeles".

Comment: @RobG-- 1) the output format of `.toLocaleString("en-US")` is ALWAYS like `'11/14/2021, 8:50:50 PM'`, which yes, might not be required to parse, but is the least you expect from your modern browser. 2) I was under the impression that the caller of this function knows that the first param should be an IANATimeZoneName (e.g. `America/Los_Angeles` and not common offset names like `PDT`.  So if one does `PDT` they are on their own.  TL;DR:  Your concerns are valid, but are extremely minute to me.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Beautiful.  Works like a charm.

Comment: This produces incorrect datetimes for several hours surrounding daylight saving times if the computer running the code is in a zone that doesn't obey the _same daylight saving shifts_ as the target zone. Confirm this by setting `TZ=US/Arizona` before launching node or in a browser with system time in `US/Arizona`. Then try the following example: `dateWithTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles',2023,2,12,6,0,0).toISOString()` produces `2023-03-12T14:00:00.000Z` which is incorrect; it should be `2023-03-12T13:00:00.000Z`. This time does not fall in the ambiguous Spring forward range `02:00 <= t < 03:00`.

Answer (score 57):

You can specify a time zone offset on `new Date()`, for example:

```
new Date('Feb 28 2013 19:00:00 EST')
```

or

```
new Date('Feb 28 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500')
```

Since `Date` store UTC time ( i.e. `getTime` returns in UTC ), javascript will them convert the time into UTC, and when you call things like `toString` javascript will convert the UTC time into browser's local timezone and return the string in local timezone, i.e. If I'm using `UTC+8`:

```
> new Date('Feb 28 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500').toString()
< "Fri Mar 01 2013 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)"
```

Also you can use normal `getHours/Minute/Second` method:

```
> new Date('Feb 28 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500').getHours()
< 8
```

( This `8` means after the time is converted into my local time - `UTC+8`, the hours number is `8`. )

Comment: Parsing any format other than ISO 8601 extended format is implementation dependant and should not be relied on. There is no standard for timezone abbreviations, e.g. "EST" might represent any one of 3 different zones.

Comment: The examples in this comment often do not work in internet explorer. As mentioned in the previous comment to this post, ISO 8601 is important. I confirmed by reading the ECMA-262 (Javascript 5th) edition language Specification.

Comment: This implementation is not time zone aware

Answer (score 13):

It's now 2023, this question is 10 years old, with 1.1m views, but I was unhappy with all of the above solutions.

The original question was:

> [if] I have `"Feb 28 2013 7:00 PM ET"`, then [...] as far as I know, I can either set the UTC time or local time. But, how do I set time in another timezone?

- [Matt Johnson-Pint's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/956779) was excellent, and *almost* was enough, but it stopped short of directly answering the question. The answer demonstrates setting a date in another time zone, but does so using the UTC offset (`+08:00`) rather than by timezone name as per the original question.

  - ***This points us to the "right" solution: specifying the UTC offset when we create the date; we just need to convert from the IANA time zone to UTC offset***
- [commonpike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652131/956779) and [chicken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842203/956779) both re-parse the locale-specific format, which [is not standard Javascript and Mozilla advises against](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#sect5)

  - They both also create a Date object that doesn't *actually* represent the desired UTC date and time
- [maowtm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35197259/956779) was also *almost* right, but again it doesn't use the only format supported in the Javascript specification.
- The other answers *all* suffer from the errors/bugs that Matt Johnson-Pint pointed out, and/or re-parsing non-standard formats.

---

#### The "right" way in 2023

Modern browsers and node.js>=18 give a list of ~400 time zones with the following query:

```js
const tzs = Intl.supportedValuesOf("timeZone"); // [ "Africa/Abidjan", "Africa/Accra" ...]
console.log(tzs);
```

For each listed timezone we can get a GMT/UTC offset by constructing a DateTimeFormat instance, formatting a new date with the `longOffset` formatter, and parsing the result:

```js
// gives '2/28/2013, GMT-05:00'
const tzname = "America/Detroit";
const longOffsetFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {timeZone: tzname ,timeZoneName: "longOffset"});
const longOffsetString = longOffsetFormatter.format(new Date("2013-02-28T19:00:00.000")); // '2/28/2013, GMT-05:00'

// longOffsetString.split('GMT')[1] will give us '-05:00'
const gmtOffset = longOffsetString.split('GMT')[1];

console.log(longOffsetString);
console.log(gmtOffset);
```

Now we can construct a new Date, properly (i.e. internally it will have the correct UTC date/time), using the timezone offset string.

```js
// Feb 28 2013 7:00 PM EST
const gmtOffset = '-05:00'; // see above to figure out where this came from
const d = new Date("2013-02-28T19:00:00.000" + gmtOffset);

console.log(d.toISOString()); // '2013-03-01T00:00:00.000Z' (UTC)
console.log(d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Detroit"})); // '2/28/2013, 7:00:00 PM'
```

Comment: Excellant work! I don't know why the browser makes it so hard to get the UTC offset from a timezone name, you have to do a dance of creating a datetime then throwing away the date.

Answer (score 10):

I found the most supported way to do this, without worrying about a third party library, was by using `getTimezoneOffset` to calculate the appropriate timestamp, or update the time then use the normal methods to get the necessary date and time.

```
var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setFullYear(2013);
mydate.setMonth(02);
mydate.setDate(28);
mydate.setHours(7);
mydate.setMinutes(00);

// ET timezone offset in hours.
var timezone = -5;
// Timezone offset in minutes + the desired offset in minutes, converted to ms.
// This offset should be the same for ALL date calculations, so you should only need to calculate it once.
var offset = (mydate.getTimezoneOffset() + (timezone * 60)) * 60 * 1000;

// Use the timestamp and offset as necessary to calculate min/sec etc, i.e. for countdowns.
var timestamp = mydate.getTime() + offset,
    seconds = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000 / 60) % 60,
    hours   = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000 / 60 / 60);

// Or update the timestamp to reflect the timezone offset.
mydate.setTime(mydate.getTime() + offset);
// Then Output dates and times using the normal methods.
var date = mydate.getDate(),
    hour = mydate.getHours();
```

**EDIT**

I was previously using `UTC` methods when performing the date transformations, which was incorrect. With adding the offset to the time, using the local `get` functions will return the desired results.

Comment: Where you calculated `timezone_offset`?

Comment: Oops, I mislabeled one of my variables. `timezone_offset` should have been `offset`, or visa versa. I've edited my answer to to show the correct variable name.

Answer (score 5):

For Ionic users, I had hell with this because `.toISOString()` has to be used with the html template.

This will grab the current date, but of course can be added to previous answers for a selected date.

I got it fixed using this:

```js
date = new Date();
public currentDate: any = new Date(this.date.getTime() - this.date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000).toISOString();
```

The *60000 is indicating the UTC -6 which is CST so whatever TimeZone is needed, the number and difference can be changed.

Comment: @RichardVergis  The question clearly states the user wants to change to local time, but doesn't state which time zone they're in. I stated my time zone as an example and the user can clearly read based off my example, they can input their time zone offset.

Comment: This is definitely working, However, I would be more interested in knowing how exactly. I know `new Date().getTime()` returns the current time in milliseconds but I don't get what the `getTimezoneOffset()` is at all. I have tried logging in to the console I can see it is -60 for me what does that mean really?

Comment: @AdeyanjuSegunSamuel check the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue running a GCP Cloud Function.  Of course it works on a local machine, but running in the cloud makes the OS default (local) for  `new Date()` irrelevant.  In my case, an api call from the cloud required Eastern Standard Time, in ISO format (without the "Z") with offset as "-0500" or "-0400" depending on DST, for example:

`2021-12-01T00:00:00.000-0500`

Again, this is not a browser formatting issue, so I am forced into this format for the api call to work correctly.

Using @chickens code as a start, this is what worked:

```
var date = new Date(); 
var now_utc =  Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),
date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());

var dt = new Date(now_utc);

let utcDate = new Date(dt.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "UTC" }));
let tzDate = new Date(dt.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "America/New_York" }));
let offset1 = utcDate.getTime() - tzDate.getTime();
let offset2 = offset1/60000;
let o1 = Math.abs(offset2);
console.log(offset2)
var offsetValue1 =  (offset2 < 0 ? "+" : "-") + ("00" + Math.floor(o1 / 60)).slice(-2) + ("00" + (o1 % 60)).slice(-2);
console.log(offsetValue1)
dt.setTime(dt.getTime() - offset1);

console.log(dt.toISOString());
console.log(dt.toISOString().slice(0,-1)+offsetValue1);
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem with unit tests (specifically in jest when the unit tests run locally to create the snapshots and then the CI server runs in (potentially) a different timezone causing the snapshot comparison to fail). I mocked our `Date` and some of the supporting methods like so:

```
describe('...', () => {
  let originalDate;

  beforeEach(() => {
    originalDate = Date;
    Date = jest.fn(
      (d) => {
        let newD;
        if (d) {
          newD = (new originalDate(d));
        } else {
          newD = (new originalDate('2017-05-29T10:00:00z'));
        }
        newD.toLocaleString = () => {
          return (new originalDate(newD.valueOf())).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
        };
        newD.toLocaleDateString = () => {
          return (new originalDate(newD.valueOf())).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
        };
        newD.toLocaleTimeString = () => {
          return (new originalDate(newD.valueOf())).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
        };
        return newD;
      }
    );
    Date.now = () => { return (Date()); };
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    Date = originalDate;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but we can use the time zone we want
we use `.toLocaleDateString()`

eg:

```js
var day=new Date();
const options= {day:'numeric', month:'long', year:"numeric", timeZone:"Asia/Kolkata"};
const today=day.toLocaleDateString("en-IN", options);
console.log(today);
```

Comment: The OP wants to parse a timestamp as if it was in a particular timezone, not generate a timestamp for a particular timezone, i.e. the opposite of what this answer does. They want to do something like "What is the time here when it was 10:30 am in Kolkata".

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answers above, I am using this native one liner to convert the long timezone string to the three letter string:

```
var longTz = 'America/Los_Angeles';
var shortTz = new Date().
    toLocaleString("en", {timeZoneName: "short", timeZone: longTz}).
    split(' ').
    pop();
```

This will give PDT or PST depending on the date provided.  In my particular use case, developing on Salesforce (Aura/Lightning), we are able to get the user timezone in the long format from the backend.

Comment: Just because I like to play pedant from time to time, 'America/Los_Angeles' is not a timezone, it's a "representative location" for a particular offset and daylight saving rules and the history of those changes (per the [*IANA time zone database*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)). ;-)

Comment: Haha, you have to post that comment on multiple answers here :P

Comment: Yep. :-) BTW, not all timezone abbreviations are 3 letters, there are many with 4 such as ChST, AEST, AEDT, etc. and `timeZoneName: "short"` doesn't guarantee an abbreviation, sometimes it produces an offset like "GMT+10" depending on various factors. I think it's more reliable to use *toString* and get the part at the end between brackets, but still not 100%. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why all these answers are so complicated. Just use `YYYY-MM-DD ZZZ` when creating a date-only date in the local / desired time zone.

Create a local date:

```
var myDate = new Date('2022-11-29 CST')
```

The date will be stored in storage as UTC, great.

Get the date out of storage and display it as local:

```
myDate.toLocaleDateString()
```

> 11/29/2022

Comment: Where do you get the three letter codes from?  Is there some documentation on which codes we can use and what they mean?

Comment: And what if you don't know whether it was CST or CDT on the date and time you're interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Try: [date-from-timezone](https://github.com/medikoo/date-from-timezone), it resolves expected date with help of natively available `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

I used that method in one of my projects for few years already, but it's now I decided to publish it as small OS project :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using ctoc from npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ctoc_timezone

It has got simple functionality to change timezones (most timezones around 400) and all custom formats u want it to display.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @commonpike answer, I wrote a function which takes an ISO String date such as `2020-10-10T08:00:00.000` as input and send an object which contains 2 main properties.

The first one is `fromUtc` is a Date corresponding to the timeZone entered as parameter.

The second one is `toUtc` which lets you to format a Date stemming from `fromUtc`.

```js
const timeZoneTransformer = (stringDate, timeZone = "Europe/Paris") => {
  const now = new Date();
  const serverDate = new Date(stringDate);
  const utcDate = new Date(
    Date.UTC(
      serverDate.getFullYear(),
      serverDate.getMonth(),
      serverDate.getDate(),
      serverDate.getHours(),
      serverDate.getMinutes(),
      serverDate.getSeconds()
    )
  );
  const invdate = new Date(
    serverDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      timeZone,
    })
  );
  const diff = now.getTime() - invdate.getTime();
  const adjustedDate = new Date(now.getTime() - diff);
  return {
    toUtc: utcDate,
    fromUtc: adjustedDate,
  };
};
const fromUtc = timeZoneTransformer("2020-10-10T08:00:00.000").fromUtc;
console.log(fromUtc);
const toUtc = timeZoneTransformer(fromUtc).toUtc;
console.log(toUtc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its 3 years too late, but maybe it can help someone else because I haven't found anything like that except for the moment-timezone library, which is not exactly the same as what he's asking for here.

I've done something similar for german timezone,
this is a little complex because of daylight saving time and leap years where you have 366 days.

it might need a little work with the "isDaylightSavingTimeInGermany" function while different timezones change on different times the daylight saving time.

anyway, check out this page:
https://github.com/zerkotin/german-timezone-converter/wiki

the main methods are: 
convertLocalDateToGermanTimezone
convertGermanDateToLocalTimezone

I've put an effort into documenting it, so it won't be so confusing.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
public static getTimezoneOffset(timeZone: string, date = new Date()): number {
    const localDate = date.toLocaleString('fr', { timeZone, timeZoneName: 'long' });
    const tz = localDate.split(' ');
    const TZ = localDate.replace(tz[0], '').replace(tz[1], '').replace(' ', '');
    const dateString = date.toString();
    const offset = (Date.parse(`${dateString} UTC`) - Date.parse(`${dateString}${TZ}`)) / (3600 * 1000);
    return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several working answers here, but somehow a lot of them seemed to get you to the string, but not back to a date object you started with, so here's my simple non-function take on how to change timezone on JS date:

```
var TZ='Australia/Brisbane'; //Target timezone from server
var date = new Date();       //Init this to a time if you don't want current time
date=new Date(Date.parse(date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: TZ})));
//Just a clarification on what happens
// 1) First new Date() gives you a Date object at current time in the clients browser local timezone
// 2) .toLocaleString takes that time, and returns a string if time in the target timezone
// 3) Date.parse converts that new string to a Unix epoch number
// 4) new Date() converts the Unix epoch into a Date object in the new TimeZone. 
// Now I can use my usual getHours and other Date functions as required.
```

Hope that helps others (if you get to this bottom answer!)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as OP which brought me to this thread and many others. None of the answers were able to "initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone".

My scenario was a user selecting a date and a timezone (for a meeting), so whether in Unix time stamp, or UTC, etc, needed that dateTime to be in a given timezone, without knowing the offset from the users local time. Example user is in ? locale needs to set a meeting for 10:30 CST without knowing offset from local time. It's surprisingly difficult to set a certain date time from a different date time.

The following solution will instantiate a dateTime object in a non local timezone or converts a dateTime object to a different timezone, while maintaining the time it was originally set at. It is compliant with all modern browsers (and pretty decently far back), does not do anything questionable with browser apis, and takes in IANA date strings.

```
    const setDateInAnotherTimeZone=(inputDateTime, timeZone)=>{
    /**
     * This funciton will instantiate a dateTime object in a non local timezone 
     * or
     * Converts a dateTime object to a different timezone, while maintining the time
     * Parameters
     ** inputDateTime, a date object with the desired time and day selected (in the local/non-desired timezone)
     *** Example: new Date(2023, 10, 10, 10, 30) 10:30 (localalized to user timezone) on 10/30/2023
     ** timeZone, the desired timezone you want to set the date in.
     *** Example: var timeZone = 'US/Central' 
     *** Requires a 'tz database time zone' name aka an IANA timezone name
     *** Usefull list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
     *** Date.prototype.toLocaleString() usng IANA time zone names is widely supported
     *** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#browser_compatibility
     */
    console.log('desired Time Zone',timeZone) 
    console.log('desired Time     ', inputDateTime.toString().split(" ").slice(4,5).join(' ').toString()) 
    console.log('inputDateTime', inputDateTime) 
    
    const dateTZShifted = inputDateTime.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone : timeZone , dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'long'})
    let timeTZShifted = dateTZShifted.split(" ").slice(4,5).join(' ').toString().split(':')
    var originalTime = inputDateTime.toString().split(" ").slice(4,5).join(' ').toString().split(':')
    let newLocalTime = [
        Number(originalTime[0]) - Number(timeTZShifted[0]) + Number(originalTime[0]) ,
        Number(originalTime[1]) - Number(timeTZShifted[1]) + Number(originalTime[1]) , 
        Number(originalTime[2]) -Number(timeTZShifted[2])  + Number(originalTime[2])
    ]
    let outputDate = new Date(inputDateTime)
    outputDate.setHours(Number(newLocalTime[0]), Number(newLocalTime[1]),Number(newLocalTime[2]))
    console.log('outputDateTime  ', outputDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone : timeZone , dateStyle: 'long', timeStyle: 'long'}) )
    return(outputDate)   
}
//Usage
let dateInAnotherTimeZone = setDateInAnotherTimeZone(new Date(2023, 7, 10, 10, 30),'US/Central')
let dateInAnotherTimeZone1 = setDateInAnotherTimeZone(DateObject,'America/New_York')
```

Expected Output

desired Time Zone US/Central

desired Time      10:30:00

inputDateTime

Thu Aug 10 2023 10:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

outputDateTime

August 10, 2023 at 10:30:00 AM CDT

or

Thu Aug 10 2023 11:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are having problem with `toISOString()`** try like this using `'UTC'` in `new Date()` method:

```
 let start = new Date();
      let event = new Date(`${start} UTC`);
      event.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      console.log(event.toISOString()); //2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple **with Node.JS support**

Pass in the amount of hours your timezone is offset from UTC

```
function initDateInTimezone(offsetHours) {
  const timezoneOffsetInMS = offsetHours * 60 * 60000;
  let d = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 + timezoneOffsetInMS;
  const date = new Date(new Date().getTime() - d);
    return date
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Was facing the same issue, used this one

Console.log(Date.parse("Jun 13, 2018 10:50:39 GMT+1"));

It will return milliseconds to which u can check have +100 timzone intialize British time
Hope it helps!!

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score -4):

```
//For Mumbai time difference is 5.5 hrs so
city_time_diff=5.5; //change according to your city

let time_now = Date.now();
time_now = time_now + (3600000 * city_time_diff); //Add our city time (in msec);
let new_date = new Date(time_now);
console.log("My city time is: ", new_date);
```