# Get server time with curl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I try to get time from server where I connect. (I need PERFECT sync ~diffrence max 1 second)

This clock is visible at bottom of page , but this clock is live (JavaScript)
Javascript - get current server time, and adds connection time to page.

This code runs if `supportPerformanceApi` is false (variable in JS on this page )

```
    this.time=new Date().getTime()

else

    this.offset_from_server=Date.now()-performance.timing.responseStart;
    this.offset_to_server=performance.timing.responseStart-
                          performance.timing.fetchStart
```

But without javascript I get 
default time + connection time.

(Clock starts from 02:00:00 i think 02:00:00 bcoz GMT +2)

I want only to get server current time and I can make own thread to control actual time (by adding to current server time , "one second per second")

Comment: Where does `curl` come in?

Comment: I login to this page by curl

Comment: Have you considered [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)? It's very hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what your constraints are.

Comment: Alternatively, the HTTP headers from the server include Date:, which tells you the server time to 1s precision.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript NTP time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522191/javascript-ntp-time)

Comment: Is there a good NTP class protocol? .. I found this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/461/CSNTPClient-An-SNTP-Implementation) but this need to include MFC lol ...